# Prevent negative numbers but allow decimals in input

Tags: javascript, html

The code below prevents negative numbers in input for numbers but does not allow me to enter decimals if I clear input and try to enter let's say 0.41

```html
<input class='input2' oninput="this.value = 
 !!this.value && Math.abs(this.value) >= 0 ? Math.abs(this.value) : null" type='number' step='0.1' id='success' />
```

**Update**
The code below allows decimals and prevents negative numbers but it does not allow me to place any condition. I also want to have one more condition of `value can't be greater than 1`: `max = "1"` not working

```
<input class='input2' min="0" max = "1" onkeypress="return event.charCode != 45" type='number' step='0.1' id='success'/>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Seems odd to do the validation on input and not when they are done.

Comment: @nicael seriously? I have posted what I have tried. It's a reproducible example.

Comment: What does your "*does not allow me to enter decimals*" mean? I see no problem entering them.

Comment: @PM77-1 clear input first and try enter 0.4

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score -1):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("success");


input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    if (input.value < 0)input.value = -input.value
    if(input.value > 1)input.value = 1
  }
});
```

```html
<input class='input2' min=0 max=1 type='number' step='0.1' id='success' />
```

Comment: snippet updated for max condition

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I could see why someone did (if I squint hard enough). You could probably explain what an event listener is and how it works with that `input` variable, etc. This is just a simple code dump, albeit commented and relatively clear for those who know JS in any capacity.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure but when I am checking your solution - it's neither preventing negative numbers nor max

Comment: enter -5 and hit enter

Comment: Oh my bad. Apologies. Can we have it in "oninput" instead of "keyup"?

Comment: no, not this way